# What is the proper way to upload a uniform array to a shader using OpenTK?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I am trying to render multiple instances of a mesh, each with a different `float` offset. To do this I am passing a uniform float array to the shader, which will then be indexed with `gl_InstanceID`. But I am getting an InvalidOperation error and nothing is being rendered. The relevant lines of my vertex shader are as follows.

```
#version 150
uniform float offsets[16]; //Uniform array declaration.
// Other uniforms

void main () {
    // Other code to assign gl_Position.
    // ...
    // Assigning the value to the vertex colour for debugging purposes.
    col = vec3(offsets[gl_InstanceID]);
}
```

I am uploading the array `offsets` to the shader using `GL.Uniform1(location, offsets.Length, offsets);`
After some experimenting, I've figured out the following:

- using `offsets[0]` instead of `offsets[gl_InstanceID]` works and the meshes are rendered, but `GL.GetActiveUniform` shows that the array's size is 1, and `GL.GetUniform` only returns the first element of the array. The `float[]` functionally behaves like a `float`.
- using a constant index of 1,2, or 3, `GL.GetActiveUniform` shows the array's size has increased to 2,3,or 4 respectively, but `GL.GetUniform` still only returns the first item and I get an InvalidOperation error and nothing rendered.
- using a variable index (i.e. `int i=0;` and then `offsets[i]`), causes the uniform to have the desired size of 16, but still only contains the first element of the array I upload, and I get InvalidOperation + nothing rendered, even when i=0;

From what I can tell, the problem is being caused by `GL.Uniform1` only uploading the first item regardless of what array I pass in. My understanding is that `GL.Uniform1(int location, int count, float[] value)` in OpenTK corresponds to the OpenGL function `glUniform1fv`, so could this be a bug with OpenTK or am I simply not doing it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The initialization of the uniform variable with an array of floats with `GL.Uniform1` works as expected (OpenTK 4.6.3):

```c
uniform float offsets[16];
```

```cs
int offsetsLoc = GL.GetUniformLocation(program, "offsets");

GL.UseProgram(program);
var offsets = new float[16] { ... };
GL.Uniform1(offsetsLoc, offsets.Length, offsets);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Using the `GL.Uniform2()` function instead of the `GL.Uniform1()` function worked for me.